# Android TimePickerDialog Shows A. instead of A.M

Tags: android, android-timepicker

[image]

Android TimePickerDialog Shows A. instead of A.M in spanish language

Any Solution to display A.M?

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    final TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                            final Date opntme = new Date();
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                            sdf.format(opntme);
                            opntme.setHours(timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                            opntme.setMinutes(timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
                            opntme.setSeconds(0);


                        }
                    }, hour, minute, false);//Yes 24 hour time
                    mTimePicker.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_open_time));
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Is it working fine for other languages except `spanish`?

Comment: Working fine in English.. My app has English and Spanish

Comment: @SarathSasi did you find any solution  ? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @AndroidLearner No.. I did't get any solution for this. Finally I changed to 24 hr view

Comment: so is it Android OS which not supported or any other technical difficulty ? i have googled a lot but unable to find any technical details for this issue